# Codeigniter fopen failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden al querer tomar "static maps"

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps

Buen día compañeros, al querer exportar un PDF con fpdf me da el siguiente error:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fopen(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=20.1129467,-98.75834&zoom=15&scale=false&size=450x400&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0xff0000%7Clabel:1%7C20.1129467,-98.75834&key=My_Api_key): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
>
> Filename: fpdf181/fpdf.php
>
> Line Number: 2555

Recientemente cambiar o renové la API Key y supuestamente yo, ya cambie en todos lados donde me pedía la vieja API key por la nueva que genere.

De Igual manera, les dejo este otro error creo que es más detallado:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Can't open image file: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=20.1129467,-98.75834&zoom=15&scale=false&size=450x400&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0xff0000%7Clabel:1%7C20.1129467,-98.75834&key=ApyKey' in /home/wii49829/public_html/prospectos/application/libraries/fpdf181/fpdf.php:541 Stack trace: #0 /home/wii49829/public_html/prospectos/application/libraries/fpdf181/fpdf.php(2559): FPDF->Error('Can't open imag...') #1 /home/wii49829/public_html/prospectos/application/libraries/fpdf181/fpdf.php(1807): FPDF->_parsepng('http://maps.goo...') #2 /home/wii49829/public_html/prospectos/application/controllers/localizacion.php(301): FPDF->Image('http://maps.goo...', 15, 160, 85, 63, 'png') #3 [internal function]: Localizacion->imprimeDoc1() #4 /home/wii49829/public_html/prospectos/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5 /home/wii49829/public_ht in /home/wii49829/public_html/prospectos/application/libraries/fpdf181/fpdf.php on line 541

Comment: Creo que lo que te pasa es que la API de maps necesita que te comuniques con ella desde un servidor con https y que ejecutes sus llamadas también con https.

Comment: Al final termine quitando eso por lo mismo que comentas, el sitio era http y no https